# How to split a row into multiple based on a quantity column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

In MS Access, I have a table like this:

**TblA_AutoID  SKU     Qty  Price**
1                      A3323   2      4.53
2                      A3313   1      22.20
3                      A3323   3      4.59

I want to create a new table (preferably one that populates automatically as new rows are added to the first table) that splits the first table into 1 row per quantity, like this:

**TblB_AutoID  TblA_AutoID  SKU     Price**
1                      1                       A3323   4.53
2                      1                       A3323   4.53
3                      2                       A3313   22.20
4                      3                       A3323   4.59
5                      3                       A3323   4.59
6                      3                       A3323   4.59

I work on a couple machines, one with Access 2007, one with Access 2013. I'm guessing this needs to be done in VBA, but if there's a simpler way, that's preferable.

Comment: Should the Price for SKU A3323 be 2.26 (ID 1, 2) and 1.53 (ID 4, 5, 6) ?

Comment: What happens to the data in the first table after it's used to populate the second table?  Is the first table's data then discarded or kept?

Comment: @PaulFrancis, Thanks for checking.  The prices in table A are already per unit, so they would stay 4.53 and 4.59 in table B.

Comment: @HansUp I'd prefer to keep the first table.  There are some additional columns not shown above that would not be transferred to the second table.

Comment: Then if rows in the first table are later updated ... say you discover a data entry error for *Price* ... must the corresponding rows in the second second table be updated to match?  How about if *Quantity* is changed for an existing record in the first table?  And what should happen when a record in the first table is deleted?

Comment: @HansUp Those are great usability questions. This is a table for my use only, so if I made any of those mistakes I could correct them in both tables.  But, it'd be great thing to prep for down the road.  So, I'd say, let's copy the AutoID from Table A into a column in Table B.  Then I can write a reconciliation function that matches Table A to Table B. But, let's not worry about that functionality (unless it's just as easy) for the purpose of this question.

Comment: What is the datatype of `TblB_AutoID`?

Comment: Both TblA_AutoID and TblB_AutoID are AutoNumber fields.

Comment: Then you can't store  a `TblA_AutoID` value in the `TblB_AutoID` field for more than one row of the second table.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant....  Table B will have it's own unique TblB_AutoID column (as shown above) and another column called TblA_AutoID that will be a number field and store the autonumber from Table A.  I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you want at this time is to add *Qty* number of rows into *TableB* from each row of *TableA*, you can load each table into a separate `DAO.Recordset` and use the data in the *TableA* recordset to drive additions to the other recordset.

I tested this code with your sample data in Access 2010.  It populates *TableB* as you requested.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsB As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngQuantity As Long
Dim i As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsA = db.OpenRecordset("TableA", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsB = db.OpenRecordset("TableB", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
With rsA
    Do While Not .EOF
        lngQuantity = !Qty.Value
        For i = 1 To lngQuantity
            rsB.AddNew
            rsB!TblA_AutoID.Value = !TblA_AutoID.Value
            rsB!SKU.Value = !SKU.Value
            rsB!Price.Value = !Price.Value
            rsB.Update
        Next ' i
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
rsB.Close
rsA.Close
```

That part is fairly simple.  However, you indicated in a comment that ultimately you intend to synchronize *TableB* with subsequent changes (updates and deletions) of the data in *TableA*.  Those reconciliation efforts will be much more challenging.